# JQuery: exclude one element of the children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get all the next html code and excluding the DIV with id `fiscal-address-info` using jquery. I started using `not` method but no success.

This is the original snippet code.

```
<div id="fiscal-info" class="content-fields">
    <h2>Datos Fiscales</h2>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div id="fiscal-address-info">Foo Bar</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

What I'd like to get in the jquery result is:

```
<div id="fiscal-info" class="content-fields">
    <h2>Datos Fiscales</h2>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    <footer>...</footer>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$('#fiscal-info').not('#fiscal-address-info');
```

Comment: But you didn't get the children...

Comment: What do you plan to do with the resulting set of elements?  As written it makes no sense since a DOM element naturally contains all of its children.  If you want to get the same element but with a child missing, you need to `.clone()` the original (parent) element and then exclude (i.e. `.remove()`) the unwanted element from the clone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the children of your first element, try this:

```
$('#fiscal-info').children().not('#fiscal-address-info');
```

If you want the parent too you can try this

```
var myHtml =  $('#fiscal-info').clone(false)
myHtml.children.remove('#fiscal-address-info');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reproduce that branch of the DOM tree, excluding the unwanted child, use:

```
var $copy = $('#fiscal-info').clone();       // deep copy
$copy.find('#fiscal-address-info').remove(); // remove child
```

You can then do whatever you want to `$copy`.

Note however that converting it back into HTML so you can subsequently re-insert it into the DOM is almost *never* the right thing to do.  HTML is only a mechanism for *transfer* of DOM structures - subsequent manipulation of DOM structures should be done using DOM methods.

Answer (score 0):

Getting `#fiscal-info` and its children, excluding the child with the ID `#fiscal-address-info`:

```
var collection = $("#fiscal-info").children.not("#fiscal-address-info").add("#fiscal-info");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('#fiscal-info').children(':not(#fiscal-address-info)');
```